# Problems with hosting - 503 errors

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, hosting, web-hosting

I am getting a 503 error on my Wordpress site. I've also tried disabling all plugins and thees but the website seems to be up for some time and then gone again.

What's a bit fishy is that the problem only occurs with the www link. I've used this tool to check results.

(With www)

https://www.host-tracker.com/v3/check/1/905be1ed-a57f-4951-bb37-252982657a4a

(without www)

https://www.host-tracker.com/v3/check/2/ca1efcbf-46b3-40ee-84bc-71d8c4583ca5

Any idea what might be happening here? The site is inewsmalta.com. Could this be due to an error in the .htaccess file?

Comment: it must be an application pool issue. Kindly check your website's application pool if it is stopped then restart it and also you can find logs. However, your website is working fine now but 503 error - application pool issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the www URL of your domain as the CNAME for your non-www domain? It should fix this issue.

Sudha